# OpenVPN simple installation

Tags: linux, openvpn

I have to make VPN between Debian 9.7 and another Linux or ASUS router with VPN support. I have seen different options for ciphers and other settings. Is there good and bad choices for OpenVPN settings and risk to have vulnerable link?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install if you want a zero-config, sane-defaults installation script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an opinion answer. This answer may get out of date easily. OpenVPN provides a guide on tuning secuirty options [here](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Hardening).

OpenVPN has three options for cryptography. You choose the ciphers on certificates, the hash used for authentication, and the cipher used for the tunnel's data encryption separately.

Generally you want to use the strongest available cryptography for both of the authentication components. As of writing, SHA256 (Diffie-Hellman RSA) is almost always used during authentication, combined with an RSA 4096 public/private key pair or certificate chain. OpenVPN has a guide for generating your authentication certificates [here](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/#setting-up-your-own-certificate-authority-ca-and-generating-certificates-and-keys-for-an-openvpn-server-and-multiple-clients).

While performance on authentication doesn't matter (2 seconds to connect the VPN versus 2.5 seconds), performance on the data encryption cipher can be a point of compromise. When using two big-core computers, performance isn't an issue; always use the strongest available cipher. When one of the machines is an embedded system, performance is limited. The two main choices for cipher in OpenVPN are aes-128-gbc or aes-256-gbc. If using OpenVPN version older than 2.4, use AES-CBC instead of GBC. On embedded systems such as routers, aes-128 might get 15Mbps of bandwidth but aes-256 might only get 4Mbps. You have to test performance yourself, weigh the needed performance and security, and decide which one to use. Never use DES or RC4; these are 'broken' ciphers.

Comment: What about ECDSA? OpenVPN 2.4 included support for that.

Comment: The stock firmware of router has limited settings: https://i.imgur.com/ici0iAE.png There are only MS-CHAPv1 and Auto for Authentication. I have to install Tomato or OpenWrt for better VPN.

Comment: @i486 PPTP is not the same thing as openVPN.

Comment: @slhck Elliptic curve cryptography is also an option. It is not as common and requires more configuration. Last I saw it wasn't a native option in OpenVPN and you have to manually install your crypto libraries on both the server and client. Given that RSA 4096 is already ridiculously beyond the cryptography strength generally required, I wouldn't recommend ECDSA to a first timer.

Comment: @Andy From what I've read RSA (including 4096) is not that strong any more. There are security experts that consider it fundamentally insecure now. There's a reason ECDSA, Ed25519, and other elliptical curve based cryptography are gaining traction.

Comment: Please show me a published and peer reviewed paper demonstrating a factorization break on any RSA greater than 1024. I assure you it hasn't been done. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers. The farthest they have currently factored is RSA768, and that took 2 years to do. Are you mixing up side channel attacks with factorization attacks?

Comment: NIST is currently recommending 3072bit RSA for long term general purpose use (see "Factoring Modulus"): https://www.keylength.com/en/4/. 4096bit RSA is obviously stronger than their recommendation.